# Join DATE type=text to TIME type=time

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using Jquery date picker and the input type is text 
When I use a normal input type=date (no jquery) 
I can easily join the date and time to be compatible with SQL

```
$e_date = $_POST['calendar'];
$e_time = $_POST['chronoEnd'];
$DateTimeEnd = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$e_date  $e_time"));
```

My questions are:
Is there options to make Jquery post type Date?
If not, how do I join type text with type time?

Please include date formatting

Comment: You could modify the plugin to fit your needs.

Comment: You have not provided enough info for anyone to adequately answer your question. Can you provide the relevant HTML and JavaScript, or better still, a jsfiddle?

Comment: there is no "jquery post type date". There are JavaScript date OBJECTS, and you can feed a PHP timestamp directly into JS: php deals with seconds, javascript can deal with milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

This is about all you need to get a time value from PHP into JS:

```
<script>
     var dt = new Date(<?php echo time(); ?>000);
</script>
```

which becomes

```
<script>
     var dt = new Date(12345678000);
</script>
```

time() produces a timestamp in seconds. Dumping that into JS with the trailing zeroes effectively multiplies it by 1000, giving you a JS millisecond timestamp. Now you've got a javascript Date object, and can do whatever you want with it.